# What telescope would I need to observe Mars's polar caps?

Tags: astronomy, telescopes

What telescope refractor aperture size would I need to observe Mars's polar caps?
I have a Levenuhk Strike NG 80mm, and I can see red disk of planet but cannot see any details on the surface.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this website](http://www.ayton.id.au/gary/Science/Astronomy/Ast_Telescope.htm), you may actually have a big enough refractor to see them, but only on a "good viewing" night, and when Mars is close (opposition):

> 4-6" reflectors or 3" refractors: polar caps, large surface features

3"=76mm

[This website](http://www.astronomics.com/main/category.asp/catalog_name/Astronomics/category_name/V1X41SU50GJB8NX88JQB360067/Page/1) also says that 80mm to 90mm will let you see the Martian polar caps:

> Martian polar caps and major dark surface features during oppositions

I hope that helps.  Your 80mm should work, although it seems to be at the lower end of requirements.  You may just need [better atmospheric conditions](http://cleardarksky.com/csk/).  Clearsky is a good website to check out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Larian! I will try to observe Mars out of city or at early morning next time. Aslo I have noticed that mars-filters can be helpful. I hope to see polar caps at opposition time, approx. begining of March.